# How to render a mesh as if made out of metal wireframe?

Tags: modeling

How to render a mesh as if made out of metal wireframe?

[image]

I wanna recreate this effect in blender, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ico sphere + wireframe modifier + solidify modififier.

Answer (score 3):

As Zion albi says you can start with an icosphere and give it a *Wireframe* modifier. You can also do it with the *Skin* modifier (in that case, to control the thickness of the branches, go in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>). The 2 modifiers give 2 different kinds of topology (to quickly simplify the *Skin* topology you can select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*):

[image]